# Web API won't return JSON using stored procedure

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to coding WEB APIs (using VS 2013) and I have tried to get a stored procedure to return results in JSON.  I have found examples using HTML for display, but I can't get it send JSON.  I'm working with that example and the error I'm seeing is "The name 'view' does not exist in the current context". I usually work though problems pretty well using the message boards (and I feel I'm close) but I just can't seem to get this to succeed. The data is there from the sproc but I don't know how to return it.  This is my first post so forgive me if the answer turns out to be obvious.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using TRYiT.Models;

namespace TRYiT.Controllers
{
    public class TRYiTController : ApiController
    {
        TRYiTEntities _db = new TRYiTEntities();
        public IEnumerable<InfoModel> Get()
        {
            var studentercord = _db.Student_sp().ToList();
            InfoModel objmodel = new InfoModel();
            objmodel.infoData = new List<info>();
            foreach (var item in studentercord.ToList())
            {
                objmodel.infoData.Add(new info { StudentID = item.StudentID, 
                                                 LastName = item.LastName, 
                                                 FirstName = item.FirstName, 
                                                 EnrollmentDate = item.EnrollmentDate, 
                                                 MiddleName = item.MiddleName });
            }
            return view(objmodel);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at any web api examples?  Because the use of the `View` method is not a part of web api.

Comment: WebApi shouldnt be returning a view, you probably want to just return `objectmodel`, or some IEnumerable<InfoModel> like your method signature

Comment: To elaborate on why you don't return view, there is no UI to a Web API. Whereas is model-VIEW-controller, the intent of Web API is to be consumed directly by other code, so it's only necessary to return the data, and not a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope, you are looking for this.

```
public IEnumerable<info> Get()
{
    var studentercord = _db.Student_sp().ToList();
    IEnumerable<info> data = (from item in studentercord
                                select new info
                                {
                                    StudentID = item.StudentID,
                                    LastName = item.LastName,
                                    FirstName = item.FirstName,
                                    EnrollmentDate = item.EnrollmentDate,
                                    MiddleName = item.MiddleName
                                }).ToList();

    return data;
}
```

**NOTE:** I have changed return type to info, because i can't see that `IEnumerable<InfoModel>` can not be returned from here, rather it makes sense to use `IEnumerable<info>` . So if you feel it is correct ,go ahead and make changes.

Becaue, as you can see that return type is of `IEnumerable<T>` , so you do not have to return `View` . In webapi, you need to return IEnumerable, so that when you execute `Get` request, you will get list of data ( for this example). But for `MVC`, you have to return `View` while invoking `controller` , whereas `WebApi` return type is not like that.

So assuming, this is hosted in "http://www.example.com" and has route defined as "api/{controller}", you need to hit `"http://www.example.com/api/TRYiT"` to get list of data.

Comment: I just try your routine but I get the error "The name 'item' does not exist in this context".  Any suggestions?

Comment: It worked like perfectly.  I finally have an example that is working completely and I hope to build off that.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather do something like

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var studentercord = _db.Student_sp().ToList();
    InfoModel objmodel = new InfoModel();
    objmodel.infoData = new List<info>();
    foreach (var item in studentercord.ToList())
    {
        objmodel.infoData.Add(new info { StudentID = item.StudentID, 
                                         LastName = item.LastName, 
                                         FirstName = item.FirstName, 
                                         EnrollmentDate = item.EnrollmentDate, 
                                         MiddleName = item.MiddleName });
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, objmodel.infoData);
    //or return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, objmodel);
    //depending what your client expects...
}
```